# How to make an AppCompat equivalent of Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen

Tags: android, user-interface, android-appcompat

Originally, the app is using

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

But for an error, I decided to use AppCompat

I did this to mimic it but still the components are not behaving the same way as the original theme.

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoTitleBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Programmatically:**

```
getWindow().setFlags(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

**Full Screen Theme for AppCompat:**

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        </style>
```